# AttributeError at /orders/ 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'orderitem

Tags: python, django

I am working on a django project where I want to display all the orders of a customer.
This is my models.py:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    date_ordered=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete=models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=False)
    transaction_id=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    order=models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    quantity=models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True,blank=False)
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And this is my views.py:

```
def orders(request):
    customer=request.user.customer
    order=Order.objects.filter(customer=customer, complete=True)
    items=order.orderitem.get(order=order)
    return render(request,"orders.html",{'order':order,})
```

When I open this template it gives me the error: query set object has no attribute orderitem. I want it to give me the orders for which complete=True and all the orderitems under that particular order so that I can iterate over them and show them in my template but that is not happening for me.
PLease help. Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
items=OrderItem.objects.all()
```

and in your template you can use a loop and give a if condition seeing your models like:

```
{% for ord in orders %}
{% for item in items %}
{% if item.order.id == ord.id %}
```

This is not the most efficient way as it will iterate over all items in your database but it may work for you

Comment: What could be a better way then..This worked out for me

Comment: It's a dangerous solution! if there's be a lot of `OrderItem` objects, this could lead to a disaster in your application. The better way is to first filter the customers orders and then the orders' orderItems.

Comment: Yes exacttly...I was able filter the customers orders but I cant figure out a way to filter order's orderitems...@mehdy the solution you told gave me the same error of query set

Comment: @rohitbumrah Did you test it using the latest update of my solution?

Comment: I had some issues. Firstly would adding related_name affect my other functions. And secondly how do i iterate over it coz earlier I was able to use if else but what now?

Answer (score 2):

Add `related_name="order_items"` to the `order` field in `OrderItem` as follow.

```
order=models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True, related_name="order_items")
```

Now you can access the `order_items` of an order like this

```
order=Order.objects.filter(customer=customer, complete=True).first()
items = order.order_items
```

Comment: @rohitbumrah updated the answer. you should call `first` too.

Comment: But what if a user has multiple orders. I want to display all of them at once

Comment: @VATSALJAIN Then you should use `all` instead of `first` and for each `order` access the `order.oder_items`.

Comment: Checkout my answer above. I also had same problem in the past. Check if it is efficient or not

Comment: `ordertem_set` will not work any more, so make sure too replace it with the **related_name** value